# Using c_url upload file to remote host, file name is incorrect

Tags: php, curl, upload, filenames, filepath

Using c_url upload file to remote host. here is my code.

```
 <?php

/* http://localhost/upload.php:
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
*/

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/home/autouvl/public_html/asmallorange/log.txt');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.test.com/test/receivefile.aspx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

echo(curl_exec($ch));
?>
```

Question: in my **receivefile.aspx**. I got the file name is `"/home/autouvl/public_html/asmallorange/log.txt"`. but I want It should be "log.txt", not full path. file can be uploaded successfully except incorrect file name.

what's wrong in my code?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/home/autouvl/public_html/asmallorange/log.txt;filename=log.txt');
```

Comment: thank you very much. as my test, seems It didn't work well. I have solved my issue, I constructed post body muanlly.